# JMeter - send HTTP Request name in email title

Tags: javascript, java, email, jmeter

Using jmeter 3.3 I am sending some request to my website an on assertion KO I am sending an email.

For this I added an IF controller with this condition:

```
!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
```

inside my if I triggers an email using SMTP Sampler.

Please How can I send the name of the sampler HTTP Request inside the email title?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you have setup like:

- Your sampler

  - Assertion
- If Controller

  - SMTP Sampler

You can get `Your sampler` name using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like

```
${__groovy(ctx.getPreviousSampler().getName(),)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Previous Sampler Name]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: it works! thank you Dmitri. Out of curiosity, why u used the comma after the getName(), is it a typo?

Comment: It's a empty optional variable parameter, see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy